# How do I save a GIF from a url?

Tags: python, gif, giphy, giphy-api

I'm using `Giphypop` to retrieve the url of a `gif`. I saved this url in a variable for convenience, but now I need to somehow save the `gif` to file. But I'm getting an error.

I think this can be reopened. My problem is Windows not opening the `gif` file after saving. Here is the code and a screenshot of the problem, sorry I couldn't post earlier.

**Code:**

```
import giphypop
from urllib import request

g = giphypop.Giphy()

request.urlretrieve("http://giphy.com/gifs/fullerhouse-3oz8xJfB6XGBwOA8HS", "test.gif")
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Did Windows 10 tell you why it could not open it? Did you verify if the downloaded file indeed is a GIF? Can Windows 10 open the file if you download it any other way? (Also, where is your code? )

Comment: @RadLexus now, Windows just said something like ''we couldn't open the file''. No helpful details. I'm pretty sure Windows would be able to open it properly if I download it the normal way, I'm just trying to learn how to do all of this via a script.

Comment: Please provide more details. This is too broad

Comment: @frlan which part is unclear? I have the url of a gif and I need to download and save it to my hard drive using a script.

Comment: you should provide the script you use to save the file, otherwise we won't be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a URL, it's as simple as a single line (and an import, to be fair):

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://example.com/somefile.gif', '/path/to/save/myfile.gif')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried last night, but Windows just said it couldn't open it. I will double check when I get home in a few hours. Are you sure this works with gifs? I saw an example that used this but for an image.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat This most certainly works. If you have a specific problem with it,you'll have to share more details (such as the error you're getting)

Comment: **The code:** `urllib.urlretrieve(http://giphy.com/gifs/fullerhouse-3oz8xJfB6XGBwOA8HS', 'test.gif')`
**The error:**
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat What python version are you using?

Comment: version 3.5.2 is what im using

Comment: @whatwhatwhat you should have tagged your question with [tag:python3] - it has been moved. Try `from urllib import request; urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://example.com/somefile.gif', '/path/to/save/myfile.gif')`.

Comment: I'm getting this error now: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined`

Comment: Well, technically I got a different error *at first* but it seemed to be coming from using single quotes, so I switched to double quotes around the url and the file location.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat arg, copy-paste error. My apologies. After the import, you should use `request.urlretrieve('http://example.com/somefile.gif'‌​, '/path/to/save/myfile.gif')`.

Comment: Ok so now we've reached the error I was getting last night - here is a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/nLVVW)

Comment: Nvm, figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib
foo = urllib.urlretrieve('htttp://www.somelink.com/file.gif','localfilename.gif')
```

Comment: Beaten by seconds by Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

If you are not a fan of urllib, you can try using the requests module:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.url.of/the-file/here.gif"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
open("./image.gif", "w").write(data)
```

Or you also can try using a shorter alternative to the code above:

```
import requests

download = lambda url, filename="": open(filename if filename else (url.split("/")[-1] or "file.html"), "w").write(requests.get(url).text)
download("http://www.url.of/the-file/here.gif", "image.gif")
```